# Is it possible to get the value of string of Toast.makeText()?

Tags: android, android-toast

If possible, I'd like to put the value of it to conditional statement (if) and put some arguments inside of it.

Comment: you mean from the resources?
Toast.makeText(c,
   `c.getResources().getString(R.string.my_resource_string)`,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Is it not possible to get the value of appeared toast message. Like if the toast message is hello. Then, you can get the value of it and you can make conditions with the used of toast message? Sorry if isnt. I'm just new to android.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hellow World!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        myToast.show();

//Now the statement below gets the text displayed 
String displayedText = ((TextView)((LinearLayout)myToast.getView()).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: there you go, you got it (Y)