# Getting the value of the toast message and storing it in a string

Tags: android, android-toast

I am new to Android. So, after clicking a button a toast message appears. I would like to store the toast message in a variable as a string after the message appears.

I have viewed this: [Is it possible to get the value of string of Toast.makeText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982322/is-it-possible-to-get-the-value-of-string-of-toast-maketext)

In the solution provided there, he has created a variable name myToast. I have more than one toast but only one toast will appear when the button is clicked. I would like to store that particular toast as a string.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can previously create one general string variable which will be changed when some button will be clicked and then you can show this variable in the toast which will appear. For example:

```
var selectedString:String = ""
```

then assign another value:

```
selectedString = "some_data"
```

and then show it in the toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, selectedString , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

### UPDATE

In general after clicking on button you will assign the latest string which will be represented in toast. So after that, you only need to analyse stored variable:

```
when(selectedString){
"test_1" -> moveFun(1)
"test_2" -> moveFun(1)
}
```

and then we have to create function for moving to next screen:

```
fun moveFun(toWhich:Int)
{
var intent:Intent?=null
when(toWhich){
1-> intent = Intent(this, FirstActivity::java.class)
2-> intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::java.class)
}
if(intent!=null){
startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

### UPDATE 2.0

Example of assigning value to `selectedString`:

```
selectedString = if(success_condition){
"good"
}else{
"bad"
}
```

then show it in Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, selectedString , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

and then analyse it :)

Comment: I am trying to make an if condition to go to the next activity based on the toast message which will appear. So, basically I do not know what message will appear but I want to store that message in a variable as a string and perform the if conditional statement.

Comment: so you don't know how to add condition or what?

Comment: I want something like this if it is possible.

toast_string = collecting it when the button is clicked.

if(toast_string.contains("###"){
move to activity 2
} 

else{

Move to activity 3
}

Comment: @SairamRavuri, I have updated my answer, can you check it please)

Comment: I understood what you wrote. So, I kept the selectedstring = "some_data" as a temporary message and then showed it in the toast and I got another toast message as "Sign_up confirmed". Can we now update selectedstring variable as Sign_up confirmed?

Basically what I am trying to do is user authentication and I do not know whether the result is gonna be success or failed. So, I want to store that message.


So, in your selectedstring I would like to get it updated when the toast appears and then the when condition takes me to the desired activity.

Thanks in advance again.